# How to display combobox in a table?RSS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

1. How to display a combobox for the current model in the table?
2. How to make the model correctly in order to display a combobox in the table?

Currently, I get the result, which is shown in the picture.

ASP.NET Core 3.1

**Problems:**
  - in the field with the combo box the current value of the field for recording is not displayed.

**Company.cs**

```
public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }        

         public Status2 Status2Value { get; set; }     

        public class Status2
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {            
            List<Company> companies_List = new List<Company>();  
            companies_List = MockCompanyData.CompanyList_prop;

            List<Company.Status2> status2_List = new List<Company.Status2>();
            status2_List = MockCompanyData.CompanyStatus2_prop;

            IndexVM indexVM = new IndexVM { Companies = companies_List, companyStatus2 = status2_List };

            return View(indexVM);

        }

    }
```

**IndexVM.cs**

```
 public class IndexVM
    {
        public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Company.Status2> companyStatus2 { get; set; }  

    }
```

**MockCompanyData.cs**

```
static class MockCompanyData
    {        
        static string mainPathForImg = @"";

        static List<Company.Status2> companyStatus2List = new List<Company.Status2>
        {
            new Company.Status2 {ID=1, Status = ""},
            new Company.Status2 {ID=2, Status = "Yes"},
            new Company.Status2 {ID=3, Status = "No"}
        };

        static List<Company> companyList = new List<Company>
        {
            new Company {Id = 1, Picture = mainPathForImg + @"~/img/number_1_blue.png", Name ="Name_Company_1", Description ="Description_1", Status = true, Status2Value = companyStatus2List[0]},
            new Company {Id = 2, Picture = mainPathForImg + @"~/img/number_2_blue.png", Name ="Name_Company_2", Description ="Description_2", Status = false, Status2Value = companyStatus2List[1]},
            new Company {Id = 3, Picture = mainPathForImg + @"~/img/number_3_blue.png", Name ="Name_Company_3", Description ="Description_3", Status = true, Status2Value =companyStatus2List[0]}           
        };

        public static List<Company> CompanyList_prop
        {
            get
            {
                return companyList;
            }
            set
            {
                companyList = value;
            }
        }

        public static List<Company.Status2> CompanyStatus2_prop
        {
            get
            {
                return companyStatus2List;
            }
            set
            {
                companyStatus2List = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
   @using WebApplCore.Core.ViewModels;
@using WebApplCore.Models;

@model IndexVM;

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<head>
    <link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">        
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-dark">                
                @{var headerMetadata = Model.Companies.FirstOrDefault();}
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Id)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Picture)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Description)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Status)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Status2Value)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (Company item in Model.Companies)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                            @*@item.Id*@
                        </td>
                        <td>                            
                            <img src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture) class="rounded-circle" asp-append-version="true" alt="No Picture">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)>                            
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="companyId" class="form-control">
                                @foreach (Company.Status2 status2 in Model.companyStatus2)
                                {
                                    <option value="@status2.ID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => status2.Status)</option>
                                }
                            </select>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Picture-1**
[image: Picture-1]

**Picture-2**
[image: Picture-2]

Comment: What is problem?combo box is rendering successfully

Comment: @Always_a_learner **Problem:** the value of the `Status` field for the current record is not displayed.
**Example:**
**1.** For a record with `id = 1`, the field `Status = true`.
The table displays an empty field. `Status = empty`.
**2.** For a record with `id = 2`, the field `Status = false`.
The table displays an empty field. `Status = empty`.
If I could not answer your question, then let me know.

Comment: Try to understand , check my answer and let me know if i estimated incorrect

Comment: @Always_a_learner @Always_a_learner In the past comments, I was mistaken. It will be more correct. **Problem:** the value of the `Status2Value` field for the current record is not displayed. **Example:**  **1** For recording with `id = 1`, the field is `Status2Value = yes`. The table displays an empty field. `Status2Value = empty`. **2.** For recording with `id = 2`, the field is `Status2Value = No`. The table displays an empty field. `Status = empty`. If I could not answer your question, then let me know. –

Comment: do you want to see Yes in status2Value Field for first row and No in Status2Value for second row?

Comment: @Always_a_learner Yes. I want the value from the data source to be displayed.
I did this: `<select name =" companyId "class =" form-control ">  <option> @ Html.DisplayFor (modelItem => item.Status2Value.Status) </option> @foreach (Company.Status2 status2 in Model.companyStatus2)
                                 {
                                     <option value = "@ status2.ID"> @ Html.DisplayFor (modelItem => status2.Status) </option>
                                 }
                             </select>`
You can use this code as an answer.
Or offer your own option.

Comment: do you need answer or you had resolved it?

Comment: @Always_a_learner I solved the problem. But, because If you are already dealing with this issue, and this question needs to be closed, then fill out the answer on the basis of my decision or propose your own version.

Comment: i replied plz close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, You want to set dropdown value: here is changes in you code:

Model:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public int SelectedStatus2Value { get; set; }

    public class Status2
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
}

static class MockCompanyData
{
    static string mainPathForImg = @"";

    static List<Company.Status2> companyStatus2List = new List<Company.Status2>
    {
        new Company.Status2 {ID=1, Status = ""},
        new Company.Status2 {ID=2, Status = "Yes"},
        new Company.Status2 {ID=3, Status = "No"}
    };

    static List<Company> companyList = new List<Company>
    {
        new Company {Id = 1, Picture = mainPathForImg + @"~/img/number_1_blue.png", Name ="Name_Company_1", Description ="Description_1", Status = true, SelectedStatus2Value = companyStatus2List[1].ID},
        new Company {Id = 2, Picture = mainPathForImg + @"~/img/number_2_blue.png", Name ="Name_Company_2", Description ="Description_2", Status = false, SelectedStatus2Value = companyStatus2List[2].ID},
        new Company {Id = 3, Picture = mainPathForImg + @"~/img/number_3_blue.png", Name ="Name_Company_3", Description ="Description_3", Status = true, SelectedStatus2Value =companyStatus2List[2].ID}
    };

    public static List<Company> CompanyList_prop
    {
        get
        {
            return companyList;
        }
        set
        {
            companyList = value;
        }
    }

    public static List<Company.Status2> CompanyStatus2_prop
    {
        get
        {
            return companyStatus2List;
        }
        set
        {
            companyStatus2List = value;
        }
    }
```

View :

```
@using WebApplCore.Core.ViewModels;
@using WebApplCore.Models;

@model IndexVM;

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<head>
    <link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                @{var headerMetadata = Model.Companies.FirstOrDefault();}
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Id)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Picture)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Description)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => headerMetadata.Status)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Status2Value
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (Company item in Model.Companies)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                            @*@item.Id*@
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture) class="rounded-circle" asp-append-version="true" alt="No Picture">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="companyId" class="form-control">
                                @foreach (Company.Status2 status2 in Model.companyStatus2)
                                {
                                    if (status2.ID != item.SelectedStatus2Value)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@status2.ID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => status2.Status)</option>
                                    }
                                    if (status2.ID == item.SelectedStatus2Value)
                                    {
                                        <option selected value="@status2.ID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => status2.Status)</option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Output Here:
[image]

Comment: Where to place the `class Status2`?
`class Status2` to embed in` class Company` or is it better to make it a separate class?

If I use a database, should the class `class Status2` be stored in a separate table?
Or is there no principled solution?
Task: I need a directory that will be the data source for the combobox of the `SelectedStatus2Value 'field.

Comment: You should make it a seperate class for it.